# JSON parse error

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jackson

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web (Spring) e preciso salvar uma data no banco de dados. Fiz uma função `Ajax` para salvar o valor, porém recebo o seguinte erro:

> JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type
>   java.time.LocalDate from String "02/07/2018": Text '02/07/2018' could
>   not be parsed at index 0

Já configurei o `Maven` para baixar as dependências para trabalhar com JSON. Abaixo, as dependências que estou utilizando:

```
    <!-- Jackson - JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Atributo da class model:

```
@Column(name = "data_contribuicao", columnDefinition = "DATE")
@NotBlank(message = "Informe a data da contribuição")
private LocalDate dataContribuicao;
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
    private @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> salvar(@RequestBody @Validated Contribuicao contribuicao, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(cadastroContribuicaoServe.cadastrar(contribuicao));

    }
```

Script Ajax:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#enviar").click(function() {
            var contribuicao = {
               "id" : $('#id').val(),
               "valor" :$('#valor').val(),
               "dataContribuicao" : $('#dataContribuicao').val()
            }
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType : 'json',
              url: "salvar",
              data: JSON.stringify(contribuicao), 
              success :function(result) {
                alert("Salvo com sucesso!") //alterar resposta
              }
          });
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Tentei várias alternativas, mas sem sucesso. Como eu poderia resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data em que você está passando não é um formato de data e data local.
Mudar paraespecificar o formatador correto.

```
@Column(name = "data_contribuicao", columnDefinition = "DATE")
@NotBlank(message = "Informe a data da contribuição")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/aaaa")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
private LocalDate dataContribuicao;
```

Aqui pode ajudar você:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper/40476708#40476708

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Aproveito aqui para dizer que agora tenho um outro erro, rs: "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String "15,00": not a valid Double value;"

Comment: Qual erro? Posta aí

Comment: Esse: "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String "15,00": not a valid Double value;"  Tenho um outro atributo no form, e também preciso salvar ele. Atributo da class model: `@NotBlank(message = "Por favor, informe o valor da contribuicao")
    @Column(name = "valor_contribuicao")
    private Double contribuicao;`

Comment: e um erro de  conversão.....vc está passando um string para um Double.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu posso resolver isso? Não tenho tanto conhecimento em JS. Preciso pegar os valores do form e passar o tipo correto para o objeto do controller.

Comment: como vc está passando so valore , passa sem  as virgulas. 15,00  para 15

Comment: @VictorAlves use BigDecimal